# detecting what javascript is being applied to a given dom element?

Tags: javascript

I am sure this is a stupid question but i can't figure it out: 
I am working on a site that has a lot of onpage animations, and I would like to know if there is any way to detect what javascript is being applied to a dom element, a method similar to right clicking and inspecting the element in chrome to view what css is being applied to the clicked dom element but for javascript.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you could use a plugin like https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firequery/ to see what's attatched to an element

Comment: You mean event handlers? There's a section for that in Chrome dev tools, besides the "Styles" column.

Comment: Thank you @dogbert http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn-history/r421/trunk/tutorials/breapoints/index.html
that seems to answer my question.
basically right click on the dom element and use the break on from the conext menu :D

Comment: @dogbert if you want to write an anwser instead of a comment i will gladly except.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can see the event listeners right on the column next to "Styles" in the "Elements" view of Chrome Developer Tools.

More info in the "Event Listeners" section at https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]